# Empty array from controller to view - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new at Laravel, and I'm having some problems setting up an update for my application. I'm trying to pass an id from a view to a controller through routing to select an specific line, and after that I need to pass from the controller to another view. Idk where I'm doing wrong.

Here's my view code that passes de id:

```
@forEach($line as $data)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{route('edit.line', ['id', $data->id])}}"><i class="icon ion-md-create"></i></a></td>
        <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$data->time}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforEach
```

Here's the route:

```
Route::get('/lineEdit/{id}', 'LineController@formEdit')->name('edit.line')->middleware('auth');
```

Here's the controller function from route:

```
  public function formEdit($id){
    $line = Line::find($id);
    $lineUp = Line::select('*')
              ->where('id', $line)->get();

    return view('lineEdit')->with('line', $lineUp);
}
```

And here's the piece of the view that will recieve the array:

```
<div class="card-body">
       @forEach($line as $data)
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('update.line', $data->id)}}">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
                    {{__('Name')}}
                </label>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control {{$errors->has('name') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" value={{$data->name}} required autofocus >

                    @if($errors->has('name'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{$errors->first('name')}}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="time" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
                    {{__('Time')}}
                </label>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="number" name="time" class="form-control {{$errors->has('time') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" value={{$data->time}} required >

                    @if($errors->has('time'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{$errors->first('time')}}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div> 
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        {{ __('Save') }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
        @endforEach
    </div>
```

Everything inside the forEach doesn't render. I can't see the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to load one `Line` or multiple? Also, why are you using the `Line` model twice in your controller method?

Comment: Your code is redundant; you're querying for a `Line` by id (via `::find($id)`), but then calling what is essentially the same query, except you can't use `$line` in the query, as it's a `Model`. You'd have to use `$line->id`, but again, that's redundant as you already have `$id`, which would be the same thing... What are you trying to do? Also, if you're trying to edit a single `Line`, why would you send it to the view in a `Collection`? Just remove the `@foreach()` loop and controls for editing `$line`...

Comment: @TimLewis I need my user to see the current data and pass the id for updating the line. I removed the useless query and leave de find::($id) and the forEach. I need my view to be able to recieve the query result, and pass back to the controller the id and new values.

Comment: @TimLewis thank you so much for the help, besides the problems you said, I had a typo when passing the id to the controller. Now it's working perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller:

```
public function formEdit($id){
    $line = Line::find($id);
    return view('lineEdit', compact('line'));
}
```

I use the `compact` [method](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.compact.php) to send the $line variable to the view.

Also, if you want to get the Line model to edit you dont need this:

```
$lineUp = Line::select('*')->where('id', $line)->get();
```

you only need this to find your model:

```
$line = Line::find($id);
```

Comment: `$line` is model or null not an `id`.

Comment: Using `view(...)->with('line', $lineUp);` is essentially the same as `view(..., compact('line'))`, so yes, they are passing the line to the view.

Comment: the ```$lineUp``` variable dont make much sense to me, what i understand of his question is taht he only wants to edit a model. He's comparing a id to a model in his query

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller:

```
public function formEdit($id){
    $line = Line::find($id);

    return View::make('lineEdit', compact('line'));
}
```

This should pass a variable `$line` to your view

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the problem is in the controller code.

```
$line = Line::find($id);
```

returns you an object (just one object!) of class Line if a) $id is an integer b) $id is the primary key c) this key exists in the DB

So, either $line is null or a model object. The next query

```
$lineUp = Line::select('*')->where('id', $line)->get();
```

cannot be successful in either case.

As I understand your intent $id is just an attribute (because you expect to have a collection of objects). So, try

```
$lineUp = Line::select('*')->where('id', $id)->get();
```